# How to take particular value from array and show in tableview

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I Have array and save all values in an arraypartno and i put that particular value in label and want to show in my cell like PARTNUMBER:-

Here's the code:-

```
 for (int i =0 ; i<[arrData count]; i++)


   {    
        [arraypartno addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Condition"]];
        [arraypartno addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"DateCode"]];
        [arraypartno addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"MFG"]];
        [arraypartno addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"PARTNUMBER"]];
        [arraypartno addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Qty"]];
        [arraypartno addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"]];
    }
```

So what i have to write in lblplate1.text for particular key,now it show the whole array values.

```
UILabel *lblplate1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 200, 30)];

lblplate1.text = [arraypartno  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
lblplate1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:2.0/255.0 green:143.0/255.0 blue:213.0/255.0 alpha:1];

lblplate1.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblplate1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding different Key Values to same array, make different arrays for different keys

Like this

```
    [arrayCondition addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Condition"]];
    [arrayDateCode addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"DateCode"]];
    [arrayMFG addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"MFG"]];
    [arraypartno addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"PARTNUMBER"]];
    [arrayQty addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Qty"]];
    [arrayID addObject:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

And in cellforRowAtIndexPath

```
lblplate1.text = [arraypartno  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Note:- Please initialize array in viewDidLoad.

Comment: OK... but i want that all data in next view, so how i pass the data in another view, if i have one array i pass that array in that view..

Comment: you can make properties in second view and pass the values to them when you are pushing it

Answer (score 1):

If you are working for a client Application then try to adopt [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). by storing the data in the form of model objects with the properties like condition,DateCode,MFG,Partno etc and store data in **Array of Model Objects**.

```
for (int icounter=0; icounter<[arrData count]; icounter++) {
                    if (objModalClass!=nil) {
                        [objModalClass release];
                        objModalClass=nil;
                    }
                    objModalClass=[[ModalClass alloc]init];
                    objModalClass.Condition=[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Condition"];
                    objModalClass.DateCode=[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"DateCode"];;
                    objModalClass.partno=[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"PARTNUMBER"];
                    [arrList addObject:objModalClass];
                }
}
```

Retrive Data From Model Class Objects

```
for (ModalClass *obj in arrList){
           lblCondition.text=obj.Condition;
}
```

Try to use MVC as it is easy for you to change the structure in case you have to add new properties or delete them.