# Is creating an object player with email and name attributes the way to go when storing name and email in a list of arrays?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsobject

I'm trying to find the cleanest solution for this before I start with this and was wondering which approach I should take. Another possible solution would be for me to store an array with all the details, such as name and email at this point, in another array.

Basically I want a list of people's names and their corresponding email address with scalability so I can increase it later. I just would like to know what is a clean way to do this.

Comment: Where do you want to save this data, client or the server side? And emails are unique and can definitely act as keys.

Answer (score 1):

Following the proper MVC architecture, you should create the modal classes and store the data in their instances.

It is also scalable as on later you want to add one more field you just have to add one more class member in the modal class.

You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955684/how-to-take-particular-value-from-array-and-show-in-tableview/14959313#14959313) where i have specified how to store and retrieve data using data modal classes:

Comment: +1 That's the way to go. And by this way the objects can be filtered based on specific conditions.